# Response time is too long symfony2 app

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a problem with response time which is too high.
For instance, I have a simple controller which returns only text (no images). In sf Profiler I got these values

**Main Request -  2155 ms**

[image: response_time]

Is it normal that kernel.view/twig eats almost 1400 ms (page with one paragraph)?
Average of response time for other controllers is 3-4 sec, sometimes more.
What can I do to speed up my app? OPCache is set up for this app.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

New question. I use APCu + opCache,

> $apcLoader = new ApcClassLoader('dev', $loader);
>   $loader->unregister();
>   $apcLoader->register(true);

Do I need these lines.. I thought that these lines are used by APCu, but with or without I am getting the same results. Looks that I do not need them ?

Comment: Where does it get the text from?

Comment: I assume that you run in the `prod` environment and not in `dev`...

Comment: Rendering a template may trigger additional subrequests.

Comment: I get text from a database. Nothing special. The weird thing is that dev works a bit faster than prod. So, these values are from dev, but prod works slowly :(

Comment: You have something with php config or your hardware. Everything seems slow. For example on my old laptop 1.6Ghz 2 cores 2GB RAM kernel.controller ~ 9ms, you have ~ 102ms.

Comment: Either what Gerry or malcolm said....

Comment: Are you by chance  using Vagrant?